# What's the atonym for related information?

Tags: meaning

I can't remember this word, it's been on the tip of my tongue for days. I am sure that this word exists but there's no synonym results I could find on Google. It means something like the inverse of correlation/evidence, "freak occurrence" possibly.

It's a word used to say something to the effect of, "you're referring to something as though it's connected". But that word describes the claim in a single word: "X information". A great example is something like;- person A sees person B in a car with a dog and then goes on to conclude that many people might drive with dogs in the car. The observation is "unrelated" to the reality or something similar, yet person A took it to have a connection and for there to be some underlying explanation. This event itself (not the observation) is an X. Talking about the event is using X information and is not very scientific.

edit: I found it. (anecdotal/anecdote, "anecdotal information")

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Not-definite-or-based-on-fact

anecdotal adjective

based on someone’s personal experience or information rather than on facts that can be checked

Comment: What is wrong with unrelated or uncorrelated?

Comment: Is your point correlation does not imply causation?

Comment: @mplungjan, it's a more precise word and sounds better, less scientific

Comment: @ThirdNews, yes

Comment: Then is it the type of fallacy, or just the a word?   Disparate: "containing or made up of fundamentally different and often incongruous elements 2 : markedly distinct in quality or character"

Answer (score 2):

The first word that comes to mind for me is "irrelevant." You might also be thinking of "superfluous" which conveys a bit more of the idea that the information is unnecessary noise. If you count "non-germane" as a single word it probably fits your description pretty well also. A thesaurus hit might give you other words like "extraneous" or "peripheral" that may also get at your desired meaning.

Comment: It's none of those but I think you are close. It's a more accessible word than that.

Answer (score 0):

*Mistaken / false inference* is one possibility; or perhaps *coincidence, unrelated event / phenomenon, presumption, generalization, extrapolation* or *jumping / leaping to conclusions*.

Comment: "Jumping to conclusions" I think is close, like "unrelated". But nothing else seems to indicate/convey as much information. It's a very clean word..

Comment: How about _unwarranted?_

Answer (score 0):

The example provided in the question is insufficient. One can draw such an incorrect inference for various reasons:

- generalization
- conjecture
- drawing false inference from true premises (invalidity)
- [misinfer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Misinfer) something in general.

Answer (score -1):

Your disparate example sounds  like a syllogism:

> "conclusion," "inference") is a kind of logical argument that applies
>   deductive reasoning to arrive at a conclusion based on two or more
>   propositions that are asserted or assumed to be true.
>
> In its earliest form, defined by Aristotle, from the combination of a
>   general statement (the major premise) and a specific statement (the
>   minor premise), a conclusion is deduced. For example, knowing that all
>   men are mortal (major premise) and that Socrates is a man (minor
>   premise), we may validly conclude that Socrates is mortal. Syllogistic
>   arguments are usually represented in a three-line form (without
>   sentence-terminating periods):
>
> All men are mortal.
>
> Socrates is a man.
>
> Therefore, Socrates is mortal
>
> The word "therefore" is usually either omitted or replaced by the
>   symbol "∴"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism

Comment: The word I'm looking for is not technical or philosophical, it's more in the range of 'freak accident' than anything more intellectual

Comment: Hmm, adventitious is "added or appearing accidentally or unexpectedly"

Comment: it was "anecdotal"

Comment: -1 The problem is Socrates was, after all, moral, wasn't he? So there's nothing contradictory to reality or logic there.